# Python - efficiently select from list based on user input

Tags: python, list

I'm wondering if anyone can help me figure out a more efficient way to select an index out of a list based on user input this is the best way I've come up to do it, the only other way I could think is to manually set the value with a loop. Just to note those print statements are in a function so I can collapse them to make the code more readable in the IDE. Here's what I have, any feedback would be appreciated:

```
def LBMethodList():
     print "Load balance Methods"
     print "____________________"
     print "1  - Round Robin"
     print "2  - Ratio (member)"
     print "3  - Least Connections (member)"
     print "4  - Observed (member)"
     print "5  - Predictive (member)"
     print "6  - Ratio (node)"
     print "7  - Least Connections (node)"
     print "8  - Fastest (node)"
     print "9  - Observed (node)"
     print "10 - Predictive (node)"
     print "11 - Dynamic Ratio (node)"
     print "12 - Fastest (application)"
     print "13 - Least Sessions"
     print "14 - Dynamic Ratio (member)"
     print "15 - Weighted Least Connections (member)"
     print "16 - Weighted Least Connections (node)"
     print "17 - Ratio (session)"
     print "18 - Ratio Least Connections (member)"
     print "19 - Ratio Least Connections (node)"

class LBMethodConvert:
LBMethodList()
ListLBMethod = ["LB_METHOD_ROUND_ROBIN", "LB_METHOD_RATIO_MEMBER", "LB_METHOD_LEAST_CONNECTION_MEMBER",
                "LB_METHOD_OBSERVED_MEMBER", "LB_METHOD_PREDICTIVE_MEMBER", "LB_METHOD_RATIO_NODE_ADDRESS",
                "LB_METHOD_LEAST_CONNECTION_NODE_ADDRESS", "LB_METHOD_FASTEST_NODE_ADDRESS",
                "LB_METHOD_OBSERVED_NODE_ADDRESS", "LB_METHOD_PREDICTIVE_NODE_ADDRESS", "LB_METHOD_DYNAMIC_RATIO",
                "LB_METHOD_FASTEST_APP_RESPONSE", "LB_METHOD_LEAST_SESSIONS", "LB_METHOD_DYNAMIC_RATIO_MEMBER",
                "LB_METHOD_L3_ADDR", "LB_METHOD_WEIGHTED_LEAST_CONNECTION_MEMBER",
                "LB_METHOD_WEIGHTED_LEAST_CONNECTION_NODE_ADDRESS", "LB_METHOD_RATIO_SESSION",
                "LB_METHOD_RATIO_LEAST_CONNECTION_MEMBER", "LB_METHOD_RATIO_LEAST_CONNECTION_NODE_ADDRESS"]
LBMethodSelect = input('Please select Load Balance method by number from list above: ')
MethodConstraint  = LBMethodSelect - 1
LBMethod = ListLBMethod[MethodConstraint:LBMethodSelect]
```

Comment: You should read through [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Best to avoid `input()` in Python 2.x. It's essentially `eval(raw_input())` meaning a potential code injection risk. E.g. you could write `1+1` as input and your script would return `2`. Just use `int(raw_input())` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep your data together and let it extend if you need to you could use this example:

```
LBMethods=[
  ("Round Robin", "LB_METHOD_ROUND_ROBIN"), 
  ("Ratio (member)", "LB_METHOD_RATIO_MEMBER"), 
  ("Least Connections (member)", "LB_METHOD_LEAST_CONNECTION_MEMBER"), 
  ("Observed (member)", "LB_METHOD_OBSERVED_MEMBER"), 
  ("Predictive (member)", "LB_METHOD_PREDICTIVE_MEMBER"), 
  ("Ratio (node)", "LB_METHOD_RATIO_NODE_ADDRESS"), 
  ("Least Connections (node)", "LB_METHOD_LEAST_CONNECTION_NODE_ADDRESS"), 
  ("Fastest (node)", "LB_METHOD_FASTEST_NODE_ADDRESS"), 
  ("Observed (node)", "LB_METHOD_OBSERVED_NODE_ADDRESS"), 
  ("Predictive (node)", "LB_METHOD_PREDICTIVE_NODE_ADDRESS"), 
  ("Dynamic Ratio (node)", "LB_METHOD_DYNAMIC_RATIO"), 
  ("Fastest (application)", "LB_METHOD_FASTEST_APP_RESPONSE"), 
  ("Least Sessions", "LB_METHOD_LEAST_SESSIONS"), 
  ("Dynamic Ratio (member)", "LB_METHOD_DYNAMIC_RATIO_MEMBER"), 
  ("Weighted Least Connections (member)", "LB_METHOD_WEIGHTED_LEAST_CONNECTION_MEMBER"), 
  ("Weighted Least Connections (node)", "LB_METHOD_WEIGHTED_LEAST_CONNECTION_NODE_ADDRESS"), 
  ("Ratio (session)", "LB_METHOD_RATIO_SESSION"), 
  ("Ratio Least Connections (member)", "LB_METHOD_RATIO_LEAST_CONNECTION_MEMBER"), 
  ("Ratio Least Connections (node)", "LB_METHOD_RATIO_LEAST_CONNECTION_NODE_ADDRESS"), 
]

def show_methods(method_list):
     print "Load balance Methods"
     print "____________________"
     for index, method in enumerate(method_list):
       print "%d - %s"%(index+1, method[0])

if __name__=='__main__':
  show_methods(LBMethods)
  index = input('Please select Load Balance method by number from list above: ')
  print LBMethods[index-1][1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use simple indexing since you only need one item? Pretty sure slices are less efficient than indexes:

```
LBMethodSelect = int(input('Please select Load Balance method by number from list above: '))
LBMethod = ListLBMethod[LBMethodSelect-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The way you use classes are most probably not the way you want it.
2. If it is a script it is a good thing to check if `__name__=='__main__'`
3. To select a single item from a list you don't need to access `list[x:x+1]`. Just access `list[x]`
4. There's a entry too much: LB_METHOD_L3_ADDR

I did a small rewrite:

```
def LBMethodList():
     print "Load balance Methods"
     print "____________________"
     print "1  - Round Robin"
     print "2  - Ratio (member)"
     print "3  - Least Connections (member)"
     print "4  - Observed (member)"
     print "5  - Predictive (member)"
     print "6  - Ratio (node)"
     print "7  - Least Connections (node)"
     print "8  - Fastest (node)"
     print "9  - Observed (node)"
     print "10 - Predictive (node)"
     print "11 - Dynamic Ratio (node)"
     print "12 - Fastest (application)"
     print "13 - Least Sessions"
     print "14 - Dynamic Ratio (member)"
     print "15 - Weighted Least Connections (member)"
     print "16 - Weighted Least Connections (node)"
     print "17 - Ratio (session)"
     print "18 - Ratio Least Connections (member)"
     print "19 - Ratio Least Connections (node)"

if __name__=='__main__':
  LBMethodList()
  ListLBMethod = ["LB_METHOD_ROUND_ROBIN", "LB_METHOD_RATIO_MEMBER", "LB_METHOD_LEAST_CONNECTION_MEMBER",
                  "LB_METHOD_OBSERVED_MEMBER", "LB_METHOD_PREDICTIVE_MEMBER", "LB_METHOD_RATIO_NODE_ADDRESS",
                  "LB_METHOD_LEAST_CONNECTION_NODE_ADDRESS", "LB_METHOD_FASTEST_NODE_ADDRESS",
                  "LB_METHOD_OBSERVED_NODE_ADDRESS", "LB_METHOD_PREDICTIVE_NODE_ADDRESS", "LB_METHOD_DYNAMIC_RATIO",
                  "LB_METHOD_FASTEST_APP_RESPONSE", "LB_METHOD_LEAST_SESSIONS", "LB_METHOD_DYNAMIC_RATIO_MEMBER",
                  "LB_METHOD_L3_ADDR", "LB_METHOD_WEIGHTED_LEAST_CONNECTION_MEMBER",
                  "LB_METHOD_WEIGHTED_LEAST_CONNECTION_NODE_ADDRESS", "LB_METHOD_RATIO_SESSION",
                  "LB_METHOD_RATIO_LEAST_CONNECTION_MEMBER", "LB_METHOD_RATIO_LEAST_CONNECTION_NODE_ADDRESS"]
  LBMethodSelect = input('Please select Load Balance method by number from list above: ')
  LBMethod = ListLBMethod[LBMethodSelect-1]
  print LBMethod
```